# How to replace a specific part from strings in odd and even index in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, replace

#### How to replace a specific part from strings in odd and even index in JavaScript?

---

I want to replace the `1, 3, 5, etc` ```` ``` ```` with `<span class="styles">` and the `2, 4, 6, etc` ```` ``` ```` with `</span>`. So that I can style the areas.

It is somewhat similar to the *Stack Overflow 's Textarea/answer&question area* or *GitHub's editor*.

---

For example, I have a string:

````
const str = "Almost ```before``` we knew it, ```we``` had left the ```ground```.";
````

When I will print it on the page, I want it somewhat like this.

```
Almost <span class="styles">before</span> we knew it, <span class="styles">we</span> had left the <span class="styles">ground</span>.
```

I have researched a lot but I am only able to extract this ```` ``` ```` from the string and I don't know how to replace in odd and even pattern.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? We expect that you'll do research and make an attempt before posting.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have researched a lot but I am only able to extract this ` ``` ` from the string and I don't know how to replace in odd and even pattern.

Comment: You still haven't posted what you've tried. You've only told us what your attempt did. We want you to post the code that you have tried and are working with because there are always many ways to solve a problem and we need to see what your approach is.

Comment: Note that [the name of this site is "Stack Overflow"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321191/215552) and the name of the other site is "GitHub". Since you reversed my edit, I thought I'd just leave this advice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search for a group between the separators with non greedy search between and take the group with new tags around.

````js
const
    string = "Almost ```before``` we knew it, ```we``` had left the ```ground```.",
    result = string.replace(/```(.*?)```/g, '<span class="styles">$1</span>');

console.log(result);
````

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through each one and do something along the lines as the following:

````js
const str = "Almost ```before``` we knew it, ```we``` had left the ```ground```.";

const parts = str.split('```')
let final = parts[0]
for (let i = 1; i < parts.length -1; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 1) {
    final += '<span class="styles">'
  } else {
    final += '</span>' 
  }
  final += parts[i]
}
final += '</span>' + parts[parts.length - 1]
````

Answer (score 0):

```
function repl(str, mark) {
    var inside = false 
    var last = 0
    var builder = []
    for(var i in str) {
        i = parseInt(i)
        if (str.substring(i, i + mark.length) == mark) {
            builder.push(str.substring(last, i))
            last = i + mark.length
            if (inside) {
                builder.push(`<span class="stile">`)
            } else {
                builder.push(`</span>`)
            }
            inside = !inside
        }
    }

    builder.push(str.substring(last))

    return builder.join("")
}
```